# How to force a sleep for a single monitor (when you have more the one)?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

- xrandr with off option: on wakeup, open windows are messed up or thrown some where... Depending on the monitor position, all monitors go blanc for a second using this option. Recovering from monitor off is frustrating
- xset: on wakeup, all open window's says in place and all good, but sleep applies for all monitors. Can I force a sleep for a single monitor with xset?

Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

- instead xrandr, disper command line tool can be used, bud it generally do the same thing just maybe more user friendly.
- xset can not set sleep for a single monitor (all or nothing).
- I can not find anything else...